# aws lambda gets restarted every now and then and there is an issue which comes every now and then

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

This the lambda  and entry point is *handleRequest*

```
@Slf4j
@Generated
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({Properties.class,})
public class LambdaApplication {

 private  Properties Properties;

 @Bean
    public Function<Event, Void> handleRequest() throws Exception {
        LambdaHandler handler = new LambdaHandler(Properties);
        return   handler::handleRequest;
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LambdaApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

another class where other logics are written

```
@Service
public class LambdaHandler {
  public Void handleRequest(Event event) {
......
}
}
enter code here
```

i have a properties file which does the follwing

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("items")
public  class Properties {

    private String appId;
    private String items;
    private String eventscare;

...

}
```

iam facing issues related to Function-Catalog

but this actually works as expected but the following  error comes every now and then

not able to check what exactly is the issue .

```
    com.dev.CLASSPATHINFO : jar=spring-beans-5.3.30.jar baseName=spring-beans jarVersion=5.3.30 modTime=2023-12-19T20:30:18.000 length=706239 jarPath=lib/spring-beans-5.3.30.jar
com.dev.CLASSPATHINFO : jar=spring-boot-2.7.16.jar baseName=spring-boot jarVersion=2.7.16 modTime=2023-12-19T20:30:18.000 length=1466387 jarPath=lib/spring-boot-2.7.16.jar
com.dev.CLASSPATHINFO : jar=spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.16.jar baseName=spring-boot-autoconfigure jarVersion=2.7.16 modTime=2023-12-19T20:30:18.000 length=1689267 jarPath=lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.16.jar
com.dev.CLASSPATHINFO : jar=spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.7.16.jar baseName=spring-boot-configuration-processor jarVersion=2.7.16 modTime=2023-12-19T20:30:18.000 length=119803 jarPath=lib/spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.7.16.jar
com.dev.CLASSPATHINFO : jar=spring-boot-starter-2.7.16.jar baseName=spring-boot-starter jarVersion=2.7.16 modTime=2023-12-19T20:30:18.000 length=4772 jarPath=lib/spring-boot-starter-2.7.16.jar
com.dev.CLASSPATHINFO : jar=spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.16.jar baseName=spring-boot-starter-json jarVersion=2.7.16 modTime=2023-12-19T20:30:18.000 length=4749 jarPath=lib/spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.16.jar
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionCatalog'
```

Comment: Are you attempting to call a Lambda function from your Spring Boot app?

Comment: Yes iam calling it from that @smac2020